# How to set FIX::ExpireTime in QuickFix C++

Tags: c++, timestamp, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using QuickFIx C++ engine
I want to send GTT(Good Till Time) order for which I need to set FIX::ExpireTime to UTCTimeStampFormat. The time portion specifies the amount of time before the order expires. For example, for an order that expires in ten
seconds, the value could be 00000000-00:00:10.000. i.e.The relative expiration time of the order in the format YYYYMMDD-hh:mm:ss.sss .

Here, lets say I have a variable: int delay = 10. i.e. I need to cancel the order if it is not fillled in 10 secs.

Can anyone please suggest how to set above value(delay) in 00000000-00:00:10.000 format so that I can set FIX::ExpireTime.

Currently I am using:

```
FIX::UtcTimeStamp expireTime(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);

newOrderSingle.set(FIX::ExpireTime(expireTime.getTime()));
```

But it seems to take current time, not 00000000-00:00:10.000.

Thanks and Regards
garv

Comment: Did you debug it ?

Comment: Yes I did. But I need to set YYYYMMDD fields to 00000000. Even if I set       time_t  t = 10 and then  FIX::UtcTimeStamp expireTime (t,0), I get 19700101-00:00:10.000 as output.

Answer (score 1):

How about to set expiration as a string?

```
message.setField(FIX::FIELD::ExpireTime, "00000000-00:00:10.000");
```